# Add-in built on jQuery framework works well on web-based outlook but doesn't on Desktop App

Tags: jquery, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We have built a custom add-in for outlook. The purpose of the add-in is to have a tab on the ribbon for an IT support form with multiple different subjects.

The code works beautifully inside a normal browser. However, I am struggling to get the JavaScript framework I use (**jQuery**) to load and run inside Outlook.

any help or Advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler to make sure JQuery is loaded from the CDN at least. Do you get any errors while debugging your add-in? Have you tried to run the add-in under the debugger attached at all?